# Why aren't the contents of my html table displaying properly in email?

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I created a table to format these 4 blocks of image & text, and everything displays perfectly in litmus' browser preview, but the images and text don't display correctly (or at all for some) in different email provider previews, nor in the test I sent to my own email:
[outlook 365 on windows render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ3Eg.png)
[proper display, rendered OL Office 365 on mac 10.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvV5k.png)

The blocks don't have the rounded corners, each image linked is partially cut off within the cell. I'm not sure where the issue is because according to litmus there are no closing tags/other errors in code.

The company I work at uses tables to build out our emails. So this is a table within the larger table for the entire email, if that's relevant. Any ideas of what is causing this issue are welcome!

```html
<table style="vertical-align: bottom; border:1px white; border-radius: 10px; cellpadding:10; cellspacing: 0; background: #ffffff; color: #005287; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: .6">
  <tbody>
    <tr height="40">
      <td valign="bottom" style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; cellpadding: 10px; width: 40px;">
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; width: 253px;">
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; width: 13px;">
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; width: 253px;">
      </td>
      <td style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; width: 40;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="165">
      <td style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; width: 40;">
      </td>
      <td valign: bottom align="center" style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; padding-bottom: 15px; width: 253px; background-color:#D7ECF8;">
        <img src="https://emailmarketer.png" width="229.5" height="110" /><br /><br /> Database Choices
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="13">
      </td>
      <td align="center" style="border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; padding-bottom: 15px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 253px; background-color:#D7ECF8;">
        <img valign="middle" src="emailmarketer.png" width="91" height="94" /><br /><br /> Powerful Performance
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="13">
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="40">
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="253">
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="13">
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="253">
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr height="165">
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="40">
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" align="center" style="width: 253px; border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; padding-bottom: 15px; background-color:#D7ECF8;">
        <img src="https://emailmarketer.png" width="105" height="105" /><br /><br /> Flexible Deployment
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="13">
      </td>
      <td align="center" align="center" style="width: 253px; cellpadding: 10px; border: 1px white; border-radius: 5px; valign: middle;  background-color:#D7ECF8;">
        <img src="https://emailmarketer.png" width="211" height="109" /><br /><br /> Scalability
      </td>
      <td valign="bottom" border="1px white" border-radius="5px" width="40">
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[broken display, simulated OL Office 365 on windows 10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQ3Eg.png)
[proper display, simulated OL Office 365 on mac 10.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvV5k.png)

Comment: BTW: I am aware that this format -using inline css and tables for overall structure- is likely archaic, but this is how all the emails are templated and I am new, so will probably not be implementing internal css in the head.

Comment: With emails, this is not exactly archaic; due to the nature of many email clients you are kind of restricted to only use the most basic CSS in inline-styles in your email source HTML.

Comment: Okay, good to know! Makes sense..

Answer (score 3):

All email clients can and will render html differently. For instance Outlook uses an html/css rendering engine from word 2007 here is what Microsoft published about outlook.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338201(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Im sure other email clients have other engines, but that is why the table probably doesn’t look as expected.

Comment: Also, any half-decent email client will not request any external resources like images referenced in the email, as that could be used to check if the recipient has opened the email, which no email client should reveal unless the recipient explicitly consents.

Comment: Welp! *shrugs* We use marketo, it's not amazing that's for sure.